# maintain selected checkbox state in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, stateful, selectcheckboxes

**Problem**:: I’m not able to maintain the checkbox state if lightning-datatable records are changing.

**Background**:: I have a dropdown with the values ‘All’, ‘Opportunity’, ‘myCustomObject’. Default value is ‘All’ (when ‘All’ is selected then I’m displaying the records from both ‘Opportunity’ and ‘myCustomObject’ in the same dataTable and if either of the other two values is selected in the dropdown then the corresponding object’s records are displayed).
Now, let’s say ‘All’ is selected in the dropdown and if I’ll select some records belonging to the opportunity, and then I change the dropdown to ‘myCustomObject’ and then back to ‘All’ then my selection is going away.
I am using the standard LWC’s getselected() property to fetch the selected records. Below is some piece of code I have used.

**HTML**::

```
 <lightning-combobox name="parentobject" label="Choose Object" value={value} placeholder="All" options={options} onchange={handleChange}>
```

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="id"
                                    data={listAllCDL}
                                    columns={_entitycolumns}
                                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                                    show-row-number-column
                                    row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                                    class="slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-scrollable slds-m-around_medium">
                </lightning-datatable>
```

```
<lightning-button onclick={handleSelected} value="Process_Selected" label="Process Selected"  variant="brand" slot="actions" class="slds-var-m-top_small"></lightning-button>
```

**JS**::

```
@wire(fetchFiles, { caseId: '$recordId', objName: '$dropDownValueCurrent'})
    wiredFetchFileList({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {           
            this.listAllCDL = data.map(record => Object.assign({ "nameUrl": '/' + record.Id }, record));
        }else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

```
handleChange(event){
        this.dropDownValueCurrent = event.detail.value;
}
```

```
handleSelected(){
        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        console.log(el);
        var selectedRecords = el.getSelectedRows();
        
        processFiles({CDLLst: selectedRecords})  
        .then(result=>{  
            return refreshApex(this.listAllCDL);  
        })  
        .catch(error=>{  
            alert('Could not process '+JSON.stringify(error));  
        })  
        
    }
```

Thanks,

Rumit

Comment: Have you tried using the `selected-rows` attribute of `lightning-datatable` to set the selected rows programatically? I am thinking if you can save the selected rows in the `handleChange` so you have a copy of the selected rows and use this to select rows when the data changes

Comment: Dear Ashwini, 

Based on your reply I even followed [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IICYQA4#:~:text=The%20selected%2Drows%20attribute%20enables,you%20want%20to%20preselect%20rows.&text=To%20select%20a%20row%20programmatically,the%20row%20key%2Dfield%20value.&text=My%20purpose%3A%20Preselect%20the%20current,lightning%20record%20page%20for%20account.) but still no luck.

As soon as my dropdown value changes my variable flushes out.

Comment: I also followed , [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308448/lightning-datatable-checkbox-remains-checked-after-multi-delete-in-lwc) and [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)